# Erro when trying to push to array from http request in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to push an object into a response from a axios get request, but i always got an 'push is not a function' error

i'm trying to push inside the .then block of the http request

ps: i'm following the example from the vuejs site

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        bitCoinValue: null
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getBitcoinValue();
    },
    filters: {
        currencydecimal(value) {
            return value.toFixed(2);
        } 
    },
    methods: {
        getBitcoinValue: function () {
            axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                .then(response => {
                    this.bitCoinValue = response.data.bpi || [];
                    this.bitCoinValue.push({code: 'BRL', description: 'Reais', symbol: 'R$', rate_float: 25.50});
                });
        }
    }
})
```

this is the error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.bitCoinValue.push is not a function
>       at site.js:21

Comment: initialize ur `bitCoinValue` as empty `array` instead of `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your response from `https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json` the `bpi` entry is a `Object` therefore you can not use `push` because it is a function for the `Array Object`.

you have 2 options:

1. set your value as the similar approach that the api responds

   ```
   getBitcoinValue: function () {
       axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
           .then(response => {
               this.bitCoinValue = response.data.bpi || [];
               this.bitCoinValue['BRL'] = {code: 'BRL', description: 'Reais', symbol: 'R$', rate_float: 25.50};
           });
   }
   ```
2. convert the object to array then push

   ```
   getBitcoinValue: function () {
       axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
           .then(response => {
               let objectResponse = response.data.bpi || {};
               this.bitconValue = Object.values(objectResponse).map(item => item)
               this.bitCoinValue['BRL'] = {code: 'BRL', description: 'Reais', symbol: 'R$', rate_float: 25.50};
           });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Openig your API endpoint in a browser, I found out that the `"bpi"` key in the response JSON is not an array but rather an object. So, instead of `.push()`ing a value, you need to set the key directly, i.e. `this.bitCoinValue.BRL = {...};`.